# R optimisation buy sell

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I need to find a solution to an optimisation problem. In my simplified example, I have a prediction of prices for the next year. I have inventory that can contain max 25 products. I can either sell or buy each month. I cannot buy more than 4 products or sell more than 8 products per month. I am looking for profit by buying for lower price than selling. Is there a package/function that can indicate when to buy and when to sell? The objective is to maximise the profit at the end of the period whilst maintaining set conditions (see the example below). A possible manual solution is provided as well. In the real application, there will be additional conditions such as that I need to maintain a certain level of inventory in winter or that the max buy/sell is dependent on the inventory level. E.g. if the inventory is high then you can sell more etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  date = ymd("2020-06-01") + months(0:11),
  price = c(12, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 16, 17, 13),
  total_capacity = 25,
  max_units_buy = 4,
  max_units_sell = 8)

# date             price          total_capacity max_units_buy  max_units_sell
#  1 2020-06-01    12             25             4              8
#  2 2020-07-01    11             25             4              8
#  3 2020-08-01    12             25             4              8
#  4 2020-09-01    13             25             4              8
#  5 2020-10-01    16             25             4              8
#  6 2020-11-01    17             25             4              8
#  7 2020-12-01    18             25             4              8
#  8 2021-01-01    17             25             4              8
#  9 2021-02-01    18             25             4              8
# 10 2021-03-01    16             25             4              8
# 11 2021-04-01    17             25             4              8
# 12 2021-05-01    13             25             4              8

df_manual_solution <- tibble(
  date = ymd("2020-06-01") + months(0:11),
  price = c(12, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 16, 17, 13),
  total_capacity = 25,
  max_units_buy = 4,
  max_units_sell = 8,
  real_buy = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0),
  real_sell = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 4, 0),
  inventory_level = cumsum(real_buy) - cumsum(real_sell),
  profit_loss = cumsum(real_sell*price) - cumsum(real_buy*price))

# date             price          total_capacity max_units_buy  max_units_sell real_buy real_sell inventory_level profit_loss
#  1 2020-06-01    12             25             4              8        4         0               4         -48
#  2 2020-07-01    11             25             4              8        4         0               8         -92
#  3 2020-08-01    12             25             4              8        4         0              12        -140
#  4 2020-09-01    13             25             4              8        4         0              16        -192
#  5 2020-10-01    16             25             4              8        4         0              20        -256
#  6 2020-11-01    17             25             4              8        4         0              24        -324
#  7 2020-12-01    18             25             4              8        0         8              16        -180
#  8 2021-01-01    17             25             4              8        0         8               8         -44
#  9 2021-02-01    18             25             4              8        0         8               0         100
# 10 2021-03-01    16             25             4              8        4         0               4          36
# 11 2021-04-01    17             25             4              8        0         4               0         104
# 12 2021-05-01    13             25             4              8        0         0               0         104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be modeled as a small Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) model.

[image]

Here is an implementation using CVXR:

```
> library(CVXR)
> 
> # data
> price = c(12, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 16, 17, 13)
> capacity = 25
> max_units_buy = 4
> max_units_sell = 8
> 
> # number of time periods
> NT <- length(price)
> 
> # Decision variables
> inv = Variable(NT,integer=T)
> buy = Variable(NT,integer=T)
> sell = Variable(NT,integer=T)
> 
> # Lag operator
> L = cbind(rbind(0,diag(NT-1)),0)
> 
> # optimization model
> problem <- Problem(Maximize(sum(price*(sell-buy))),
+                    list(inv == L %*% inv + buy - sell,
+                         inv >= 0, inv <= capacity,
+                         buy >= 0, buy <= max_units_buy,
+                         sell >= 0, sell <= max_units_sell))
> result <- solve(problem,verbose=T)
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.47
84 rows, 36 columns, 119 non-zeros
*     0: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (12)
*    35: obj = -1.040000000e+002  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.47
84 rows, 36 columns, 119 non-zeros
36 integer variables, none of which are binary
Integer optimization begins...
+    35: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
+    35: >>>>> -1.040000000e+002 >= -1.040000000e+002   0.0% (1; 0)
+    35: mip = -1.040000000e+002 >=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 1)
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
> cat("status:",result$status)
status: optimal
> cat("objective:",result$value)
objective: 104
> print(result$getValue(buy))
      [,1]
 [1,]    4
 [2,]    4
 [3,]    4
 [4,]    4
 [5,]    4
 [6,]    0
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    4
 [9,]    0
[10,]    4
[11,]    0
[12,]    0
> print(result$getValue(sell))
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    0
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    8
 [7,]    8
 [8,]    0
 [9,]    8
[10,]    0
[11,]    4
[12,]    0
> print(result$getValue(inv))
      [,1]
 [1,]    4
 [2,]    8
 [3,]   12
 [4,]   16
 [5,]   20
 [6,]   12
 [7,]    4
 [8,]    8
 [9,]    0
[10,]    4
[11,]    0
[12,]    0
>
```

Comment: This looks very promising. Do you think it is possible to add more complex constraints?An example would be that if the inventory level is above 50% of its total capacity, you can sell 8 pieces (as in the original question). However, if it is below 50%, you can only sell 6?

Comment: Yes. That is possible. There is a modeling issue here, however. Usually, we look at `buy` and `sell` as things that happen **during** period t (we call them **flow variables**). `inv` is a **stock variable**, and is measured **at the end** of period t. To say that `sell[t]` and `buy[t]` depend on `inv[t]` is a bit strange (we are going backward in time). Of course, we can model it and solve it (we solve as simultaneous equations, so we can do these things). But, it may not make sense in the real world. Probably we should look at `inv[t-1]` in order to change `buy[t]` and `sell[t]`.

Comment: Agreed that inv[t-1] is more appropriate for buy[t] and sell[t]. Do  you happen to know how I could include such condition in the code? E.g. if inv[t-1]/capacity >= 0.5 then sell[t] = max_units_sell else sell[t] = 0.75 * max_units_sell

Comment: You need a binary variable to create 2 segments for the inventory. The math is not difficult but more than I can put in a comment box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have asked a new question with max buy/sell dependent on the stock level here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900256/r-optimisation-max-buy-sell-dependent-on-stock-level. Feel free to join in there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Added the possibility to have an initial inventory and created a function to do the optimisation step-wise to account stock-level dependent buy/sell.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(CVXR)

init_fce <- function(.df_storage, .df_bounds, .type = "max"){
  if(.type == "max"){
    .df_storage$max_buy <- max(.df_bounds$max_buy)
    .df_storage$max_sell <- max(.df_bounds$max_sell)
  } else if(.type == "min"){
    .df_storage$max_buy <- min(.df_bounds$max_buy)
    .df_storage$max_sell <- min(.df_bounds$max_sell)
  } else if(.type == "mean"){
    .df_storage$max_buy <- mean(.df_bounds$max_buy)
    .df_storage$max_sell <- mean(.df_bounds$max_sell)
  }

  .df_storage
}
optim_fce <- function(.df){
  
  # Decision variables
  m_inv_tot = Variable(nrow(.df), integer = T)
  m_buy = Variable(nrow(.df), integer = T)
  m_sell = Variable(nrow(.df), integer = T)
  # Lag operator
  m_L = cbind(rbind(0, diag(nrow(.df) - 1)), 0)
  
  objetive <- Maximize(sum(.df$price*(m_sell-m_buy)))
  
  constraints <- list(
    m_inv_tot == m_L %*% m_inv_tot + .df$inv_init + m_buy - m_sell, # L %*% result$getValue(inv) + result$getValue(buy) - result$getValue(sell)
    m_inv_tot >= 0, m_inv_tot <= .df$capacity,
    m_buy >= 0, m_buy <= .df$max_buy,
    m_sell >= 0, m_sell <= .df$max_sell
  )
  
  problem <- Problem(objetive, constraints)
  result <- solve(problem) # , verbose=T
  
  .df <- .df %>%
    mutate(
      buy = (result$getValue(m_buy) %>% as.vector()),
      sell = (result$getValue(m_sell)  %>% as.vector()),
      inventory_real = (result$getValue(m_inv_tot) %>% as.vector())
    )
  
  .df
}
set_limits_fce <- function(.df_storage, .df_bounds){
  .df_storage <- .df_storage %>%
    select(-max_buy, -max_sell) %>%
    mutate(capacity_usage_pct_prec = lag(inventory_real, default = inv_init[1])/capacity) %>%
    crossing(.df_bounds %>% select(-segment)) %>%
    filter(capacity_usage_pct_prec >= lbound, capacity_usage_pct_prec < ubound) %>%
    mutate(
      within_bounds = (buy <= max_buy) & (sell <= max_sell) 
    ) %>%
    select(-lbound, -ubound)

  .df_storage
}
get_results <- function(.df_storage){
  if( any(!.df_storage$within_bounds) ){
    print("result not within bounds")
  } else{
    .df_storage$profit <- .df_storage$sell * .df_storage$price - .df_storage$buy * .df_storage$price
    print(sum(.df_storage$profit))
  }
  
  .df_storage
}


A1_storage <- tibble(
  date = ymd("2020-06-01") + months(0:11),
  price = c(12, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 16, 17, 13),
  inv_init = c(3, rep(0, 11)),
  capacity = 25
)

A2_bounds <- tibble(
  segment = c("0%-30%", "30%-65%", "65%-70%", "70%-100%"),
  lbound = c(0, 0.3, 0.65, 0.7), 
  ubound = c(0.3, 0.65, 0.7, 1),
  max_buy = c(4,3,2,2),
  max_sell = c(4,6,6,8)
)

B1_max <- init_fce(A1_storage, A2_bounds, .type = "max") %>%
  optim_fce() %>%
  set_limits_fce(.df_bounds = A2_bounds) %>%
  get_results() %>%
  optim_fce() %>%
  set_limits_fce(.df_bounds = A2_bounds) %>%
  get_results() %>%
  optim_fce() %>%
  set_limits_fce(.df_bounds = A2_bounds) %>%
  get_results() %>%
  optim_fce() %>%
  set_limits_fce(.df_bounds = A2_bounds) %>%
  get_results()
```